# Is my code problematic? ChatGPT say it is (infinite recursion)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using ChatGPT to help me while learning flutter, however, it said I had a problem with my code being infinite recursive while I was debugging another issue. Is this true? How can I change it to not be infinitely recursive, if that is the case?

How I call/create my widget from main.dart:

```
LikeButton(postId: post.id).create()
```

My LikeButton.dart widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'like_cubit.dart';

class LikeButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const LikeButton({required this.postId, super.key});
  final String postId;

  Widget create() {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => LikeCubit(postId: postId),
      child: LikeButton(postId: postId),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LikeCubit, LikeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                state.isLiked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                color: state.isLiked ? Colors.pink : Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () => context.read<LikeCubit>().toggleLike(),
            ),
            Text(
              state.likes.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

ChatGPT reacted on this row:

```
child: LikeButton(postId: postId),
```

If I remove that line, the widget won't render. Is my code problematic? If that is true, then how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tbh i never saw it in production to create a separate create function to build the widget. Why don't you just put the BlocProvider in the build function?

If you had recursion, your entire app would likely hang without a termination condition. I don't think that's the case with yours.

**What I can imagine:**

You have a class called LikeButton, and within this class, there's a function called create. In the create function, you create an object of the LikeButton class again. This might be the reason why it's flagged as recursion.

Comment: Matter of opinion, tools that give you advantages and increase productivity should be used. Saying please don't do that without any justification is on the same level as the comments above.

Comment: Justifications are numerous.  Simplest is ChatGPT stopped training in 2021, but also this: Beware: LLMs generate *plausible* text. Not *most likely* text, or *accurate* text. Just believable  text denoted with confidence. They are great as a creative assistant, but frequently bad as an authoritative source.